# jsPlumb: iterate on all connections and list from to in console

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

As per title
I would like to "read" all connections and list them in the console.
May you help as I am quite rookie on the API?
Thank You

Comment: I answered below. Feel free to ask if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method provided by the API that allow you get all connections. You have to use `getAllConnections()` on your jsPlumb instance. Check official [API documentation](https://community.jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html#method_getAllConnections) for more informations.

UPDATE : [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/up5yctjz/) (see console logs)

Comment: @BrunoC I forked a random fiddle and added what you're trying to achieve. Check console logs for arrays of connections. I made a mistake : you have to use `getAllConnections()` not `getConnections()`. Hope it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH

Comment: Here's the fragment of code that I needed:
                                                   
    $.each(firstInstance.getConnections("someScope"), function (idx, connection) {
   console.log("source "+ connection.sourceId);
   console.log("source "+ document.getElementById(connection.sourceId).innerText);
      console.log("target "+ connection.targetId);
      
  });